# Are bounty parameters network-wide or per-site settings?

Tags: support, bounties

I wonder whether various parameters related to bounties can be changed locally on one SE site or only network-wide. (By parameters related to bounties I mean things like duration of bounties, grace period, how soon can be bounty awarded, names of the reasons for offering bounties, number of simultaneous bounties, minimum possible bounty, etc.) Can all/some of them only be changed network-wide? Can all/some of them be changed locally for one particular site in the Stack Exchange network?

My main reason for asking this is that I have seen some feature requests on per-site-metas about various parameters related to bounties.<sup>1</sup> Probably it is perfectly fine to discuss proposed changes to bounty system locally first. (It is possible that in such discussion the OP will learn why such change would not be good idea or they will be directed by more experienced users to previous discussions of the same issue on meta.SE.) But if it is only possible to change them network-wide, at some point it will be necessary to discuss the changes also here.

To me the most likely answers seems to be that such settings are network-wide. And answers to the two feature request from meta.gis.stackexchange linked below seem to confirm this. (However, it might theoretically still be possible that the answers are only related to those particular feature requests.) Additionally, I guess that similar requests might appear again, so it could be good to have some official confirmation on how these things work. And it would probably be much better visible (and findable) here than on some per-site-meta.

---

<sup>1</sup> The examples which I saw or was able to find:

- [Bounties: no premature awards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25015) (meta.math.SE)
- [Bounty grace time insufficient to study the solutions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16710) (meta.math.SE)
- [Is bounties period sufficient?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2936) (meta.MathOverflow)
- [Why is it not possible to offer a bounty for longer than 7 days?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3530) (meta.MathOverflow)
- [Rewarding bounty after bounty finished when question posted before end of bounty?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4149) (meta.GIS)
- [If no answers are offered in a bounty, automatic message should not be “you must award answer”](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4245) (meta.GIS)

Comment: AFAIK, bounty parameters are network-wide.